# Volume of set P=(hx,hy,h)

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I rarely ask anything here, and I searched quite a while before posting this question. But I really can't imagine how this set looks like. I need to draw the set and compute the volume.
$$ P=\{\begin{pmatrix}hx\\hy\\h\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb R^3\mid -1\le x,y\le 1,0\le h\le 1\} $$
I figured that:
$$ hx\in[-1,\infty),hy\in(-\infty,1] $$
Can you confirm that?

Would be very nice if someone can explain to me how I can plot such sets with matlab for e.g.
If I can see the plot, it's somehow easier for me to compute:
$$ \int_P 1d\lambda^3$$
Cheers.

Comment: The easiest way to visualize something like this is with slices of constant $h$.  So for $h=0$, you get a single point.  For $h=1$ you get a square parallel to xy-plane at z=1 with sides of length 2.  Play with it some more, and you will see it is a pyramid.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of thought P isn't randomly set. So its either a pyramid or paraboloid.But you have no idea how to draw such sets on matlab or wolfram alpha?

Comment: By the statement $-1\le x,y\le1$ I presume that you mean $-1\le x\le1$ and $-1\le y\le1$ and not $-1\le x$ AND $y\le1$?

Comment: @John its stated exactly like that on my homework sheet. So I assumed the boundaries are infty and -infty... but then the P isnt compact and measurable or?

Comment: The statement is, at best, ambiguous. I suspect your teacher was trying to economize and intended the first interpretation so that you would get the bounded image indicated by @Paul.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now its clear to me.